# Delete Asterisk call file before Maxretries is reached

Tags: asterisk, telephony

I have created an [Asterisk call file](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Asterisk+Call+FIles) with Maxretries = 3 and RetryTime = 300.  Occasionally I need to remove the call file after 2 retries.  How would I stop Asterisk making the third call attempt?

Comment: What is the reason or condition to occasionally need only 2 retries?

Comment: I receive an alarm.  I create a call file with the 3 maxretries, that spans over an hour.  Occasionally that alarm will clear after 30 minutes and I no longer need to notify the user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is currently no way to do that without removing the call file from your spooling directory (usually: /var/spool/asterisk/outgoing).

What you need to do (if you need to kill the retry attempts), is:

```
rm /var/spool/asterisk/outgoing/<callfilename>
```

Another way to handle this is pragmatically, via your dialplan callbacks. For instance:

Let's say your callfile looks like the following:

```
Channel: SIP/flowroute/18002223333
Context: my_code
Extension: s
Priority: 1
MaxRetries: 3
```

And you want to make your callfile retry the call two times (at most). You could write your dialplan code (to implement `my_code`) as follows:

```
[my_code]

exten => s,1,ExecIf($[ !${DB_EXISTS(call/tries)} ]?Set(DB(call/tries)=0))
exten => s,n,Set(DB(call/tries)=${MATH(${DB(call/tries)}+1,i)})
exten => s,n,NoOp(your code here...)
exten => s,n,GotoIf($[ ${DB(call/tries)} > 1 ]?end,1)

exten => end,1,DBDel(call/tries)
exten => end,n,System(rm /var/spool/asterisk/outgoing/<name>)
exten => end,n,Hangup()
```

This will store the state of the callfile in the Asterisk database, and do some manual counting to verify that the call has been attempted < 3 times (if not, then it'll hangup).

This method is obviously not optimal (as it's much easier to control this behavior from the application you wrote which actually spools the callfile), but it will work.

Hopefully that helps!